# Is there any way to name unique index in Fluent nHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent

Is there any way to set name for unique index when generating schema with `SchemaExport(config).Build(true, true)`?

I tried to set in mapping class:

```
Map(x => x.Name)
    .Length(50)
    .Not.Nullable()
    .UniqueKey("UNQ_InstitutionTypes_Name");
```

But, this way it sets index, but doesn't sets name.

Comment: When formatting code that spans multiple lines, you need to prefix each line with four spaces.  The backtick is only for code that takes one line.  See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there isn't a way. I solved this problem using following technique.

When you build the SessionFactory use the ExposeConfiguration method to apply additional configuration to your session factory:

```
return Fluently.Configure()
    .ProxyFactoryFactory(typeof(ProxyFactoryFactory))
    .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(connectionString)
        .Mappings(m =>
        {
            m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Entities.BaseEntity>();
            m.FluentMappings.Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<Entities.BaseEntity>();
        })
        .ExposeConfiguration((cfg => BuildDatabase(cfg)))
        .BuildSessionFactory();

private static void BuildDatabase(Configuration cfg, IDatabaseConfiguration configurationManager)
{
    cfg.AddXmlFile(@"Mappings\Hbm\Indexes.hbm.xml");
    new SchemaExport(cfg).SetOutputFile(SchemaOutputFileName).Create(false, false);
}
```

The actual Indexes.hbm.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <database-object>
    <create>
      CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Idx_TestRun_SerialNumber] ON [dbo].[TestRun]
      (
      [SerialNumber] ASC
      )
    </create>
    <drop></drop>
  </database-object>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

You can put any valid SQL statements inside the create/drop statements. This comes in handy if you need to create index with multiple columns in specific order.

Comment: Maybe this answer is correct, but it is not what I would want use in practice. Schema generation is nice feature, but no 100% useable - big part of it must be done by hand (or additional script): UNQ index names, check constraints etc. Auxilarity objects - too much work, for small effect. For my question, I think, best answer is at this link: http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2011/07/nhibernate-playing-with-mapping-by-code.html